# Add a pop up when an item is clicked

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

am a newbie in jquery developing an online shopping site. i would like to know how to add a pop up an each item with in a foreach loop. such that when a user clicks on an item retrieved from the database, a pop up shows add to cart, price and name of that particular item.
I would really appreciate if some one helps me with a code example. thanks in advanced

Comment: Have you tried so far? Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some hints on writing a good-quality question.

Comment: are you using any framework such as Bootstrap?

Comment: @RamisWachtler am using plain php. t

Answer (score 0):

I would use JQuery UI Dialog see example below:

```js
$("#addToCart").click(function (){
  $("#popup").dialog({
    title:"Hello Popup",
    buttons: [
    {
      text: "Cool!",
      icons: {
        primary: "ui-icon-heart"
      },
      click: function() {
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
      }
    }
  ]
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<button id="addToCart">Add to cart</button>
<div id="popup" style="display:none;">
  <p>Conent of popup :=)</p>
</div>
```